# How to get arraybuffer from not completed request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How can I get already downloaded part of arraybuffer, if request is not yet complete? I'm trying to play an audio stream and there is no end in it. I'm using XMLHttpRequest, there is attribute `response`, but it is null until request is finished.

Comment: I don't think `XMLHttpRequest` is made for streaming.

Comment: @Bergi, can you suggest some alternative?

Comment: Wasn't there some WebRTC Audio streaming api? But I could be wrong, and there are other (better) solutions.